# Android Gradle - Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Ao importar [um projeto do Github](https://github.com/lvaccaro/Android-Sliding-Tabs-And-Navigation-Drawer-With-Material-Design) usando o **Android Studio 3.0.1** obtive o seguinte erro no Gradle:

> Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix(). The
>   version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method. To
>   resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of
>   Gradle you connect to. Alternatively, you can ignore this exception
>   and read other information from the model.

Eu já tentei fazer essas mudanças, mas não tive sucesso:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546849/unsupported-method-baseconfig-getapplicationidsuffix

Eu sou novo no android. Ainda não entendo muito sobre Gradle. Abaixo segue o estados dos meus arquivos Gradle no Android Studio 3.0.1

Qualquer ajuda é muito apreciada.

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "luck.materialdesign.tabsnavigator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
}
```

**local.properties**:

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Sat Jan 27 00:26:41 BRST 2018
sdk.dir=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
```

**gradle-wrapper-properties**:

```
#Sat Jan 27 01:01:59 BRST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver com da seguinte maneira.

Edite o arquivo build.gradle para usar uma versão mais antiga:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixei uma versão mais antiga do Gradle aqui: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Extraia e cole conteudo na pasta Gradle do Android Studio, no Mac o caminho é Aplicações > Android Studio > Contents > Gradle

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora force o Android Studio a usar a versão mais antiga do Gradle alterando as configurações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de um Build > Clean Project e Rebuild Project

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Android vai pedir pra você atualizar para uma versão mais recente. Ignore essa mensagem.

A partir de agora você já deve ser capaz de trabalhar no seu aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]